# Intellij IDEA OSX Python Development Headaches

Tags: python, macos, intellij-idea, pydev

I recently started working at a Java shop where staff primarily use IntelliJ IDEA on Macs for development. I am in charge of writing automated tests for a data centric project, and my go-to language for this is Python. In the past, I have used PyCharm on Linux and Windows with great success, but configuring IntelliJ IDEA for Python on OSX has been confusing to me. So far, I have had no issues setting up a project and getting it to run Python scripts, but each time I try using the debugger, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/Users/{USER}/Library/Application Support/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

So far, Googling around has turned up hardly anything useful - and most of JetBrains's help manuals are PyCharm focused, which is rather unhelpful in the IntelliJ context. Has anyone else come across something like this? I'm looking for insight into what exactly is going wrong here.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing the plugin?   There's definitely something wrong with the path above, it should have an IntelliJ<version number> between the `Application Support/python` and the `helpers` (at least by what's on my system).   I am running IntelliJ 13 with the python plugin and have been able to debug without any problems with it.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. I forgot that I had manually installed the Python plugin at some point early on, and when that happened, the wrong path was set somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling and re-installing the plugin? There's definitely something wrong with the path above, it should have an `IntelliJ<version number>` between the `Application Support/python` and the `helpers` (at least by what's on my system). I am running IntelliJ 13 with the python plugin and have been able to debug without any problems with it.